# React setState variable issue

Tags: reactjs

I'm am using React to set the visbility (isMarkerShown) of a marker when I click a menu item which is handle by my handleMarker(). I get an undefined value if I tried to set the state like how I did below.

```
state = {
    collapsed: false,
    visible: false,
    marker: {
      isMarkerShown: false,
      lat: 0,
      lng: 0,
    },
  };

handleMarker() {
    this.setState({marker: this.setState({isMarkerShown: true})});
    console.log(this.state.marker);
  }
```

Comment: Tip: don't try to use a new `state` right after you used `setState`. The `setState` is asynchronous, if you want to use the new state, use the `callback` of `setState`. Just a complement to the answers below.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you might be trying to maintain the rest of the marker props while changing `isMarkerShown`. If that's the case, the following approach may help:

```
handleMarker() {
  this.setState({ 
    marker: {
      ...this.state.marker,
      isMarkerShown: true
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: I guess it would be better to use a callback in this case

Comment: Thanks a bunch!!! I was able to put my markers down on Google Maps correctly.

Answer (score 1):

`setState` function is a `void` function - it does not return anything. So actually if you are assigning it to some variable, it will hold an `undefined` value.

Just try to set the state directly:

```
this.setState((prevState) => ({ 
   marker: {
      ...prevState.marker,
      isMarkerShown: true,
   },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to access value of current/previous state while setting state- like toggling on/off- you can access it directly within the setState call. You can also use **functional setState** to ensure your state updates happen in order:

```
this.setState(prevState => ({ marker: { ...prevState.marker, isMarkerShown: !prevState.marker.isMarkerShown } }))
```